# JQuery: Getting previous element

Tags: jquery

I want to get the first previous h3-tag of a set of elements.

Example:

```
<h3>Any title</h3>
<div>First></div>
<div>Second></div>
<div>Third></div>

<h3>Get result</h3>
<div>First></div>
<div>Second></div>
<div class="click">Third></div>
```

`$('.click')` should give me the result `<h3>Get result</h3>`. But it is not the direct previos element, so my attempt doesn't work:

```
$('.click').prev('h3').text();
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/36p60n5u/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**jQuery docs - `.prev()`**](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):
>
> Description: Get the ***immediately*** preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

As stated above, `.prev()` will get the ***immediately*** preceding sibling element. Therefore you should use [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) in combination with [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) or [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) in order to get the first match:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ly3fe4v/)

```
$('.click').prevAll('h3').first().text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) and [`:first Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/). Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.click', function() {
    $('#result').text($(this).prevAll('h3:first').text());
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/36p60n5u/2/)